# Access denied when added entrypoint (dockerfile)

Tags: linux, docker

I just started learning how to create your own dockerfile and image, but I keep getting `/bin/sh: 1: /app/app.sh: Permission denied` when running `docker run --rm 9c33` (my image id is 9c3321cd2fe82768cc953d3e082f26c5583465a864be2d47b4187148088f4e58)

My docker file contains:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY . /app
RUN apt -y update && apt -y install curl
ENTRYPOINT /app/app.sh
```

It worked fine before adding the entrypoint

I tried using chmod +x to give me permission to that specific file, but I receive the same message of denied access
[Here is an image of my folders, if it helps. I am running my commands from this location as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I718G.png)

When running ls -la, here is the output

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 skyzreal skyzreal 4096 Jun 14 10:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 skyzreal skyzreal 4096 Jun 14 10:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 skyzreal skyzreal  113 Jun 15 09:50 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 skyzreal skyzreal   89 Jun 14 10:36 Dockerfile:Zone.Identifier
-rwxr-xr-x  1 skyzreal skyzreal  876 Jun 14 10:36 app.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 skyzreal skyzreal   89 Jun 14 10:36 app.sh:Zone.Identifier
drwxr-xr-x  2 skyzreal skyzreal 4096 Jun 14 10:39 include
-rw-r--r--  1 skyzreal skyzreal  169 Jun 14 10:36 ubuntu.Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 skyzreal skyzreal   89 Jun 14 10:36 ubuntu.Dockerfile:Zone.Identifier
```

Comment: Can you give us the output of `ls -la` in the folder where `app.sh` is located?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  3 skyzreal skyzreal 4096 Jun 14 10:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 skyzreal skyzreal 4096 Jun 14 10:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 skyzreal skyzreal  113 Jun 15 09:50 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 skyzreal skyzreal   89 Jun 14 10:36 Dockerfile:Zone.Identifier
-rwxr-xr-x  1 skyzreal skyzreal  876 Jun 14 10:36 app.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 skyzreal skyzreal   89 Jun 14 10:36 app.sh:Zone.Identifier
drwxr-xr-x  2 skyzreal skyzreal 4096 Jun 14 10:39 include
-rw-r--r--  1 skyzreal skyzreal  169 Jun 14 10:36 ubuntu.Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 skyzreal skyzreal   89 Jun 14 10:36 ubuntu.Dockerfile:Zone.Identifier

Comment: Modified the post to show the output, should be easier to read

Comment: Try running `chmod 755 ./app.sh` beforehand: `RUN ["chmod", "755", "/app/app.sh"]`

Comment: Great. I will add it as an answer to make it easier for others to find. Consider approving the answer if it helped you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to filesystems, there are usually permissions that one needs to set up in order to be able to read, write and/or execute a file. In most `unix` based systems, permissions can be changed using the `chmod` command.

To grant `rwxr-xr-x` permission (which is required if you want to run a `sh` file), you'd need to execute the following command:

```
chmod 755 /app/app.sh
```

In order to do this via `docker`, you can use the `RUN` command which basically takes in an array of strings and executes them as a command, adding a space in between each string:

```
RUN ["chmod", "755", "/app/app.sh"]
```

This should solve the issue.

Additionally, most `unix` based systems also provide a way to grand access to a specific `user` (as in `root` or in OP's case `skyzreal`). To change ownership of a file, you will need to use the `chown` command:

```
RUN ["chown", "your_user:your_user", "/path/to/file"]
```

These commands are quite simple to learn but are very important because even if you know how to use `docker`, if you don't know about most basic command line tools and commands, you are doomed to get stuck at some point.

Comment: The `chmod 0755` recipe will make the script readable and executable by all users.  You often do _not_ want to `chown` the script to the user running the container: if you don't `chown` it then you can't overwrite it, accidentally or otherwise.